# How do I display an alert popup from another Class that is not a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift3, uialertcontroller

I have the following Swift 3 code in a separate swift file in another class.

```
class Login{

     func showAlert(message :String){

        let alertController2 = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "A error occured when checking credentials, try again later.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alertController2.addAction(defaultAction)
        self.present(alertController2, animated: true, completion: nil)
     }
}
```

But I get a red error:

> **Use of unresolved identifier 'UIAlertController'**

How can I create a popup informing the user that something went wrong?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to `import UIKit` in order to make `UIAlertController` visible to your class.

This code will obtain the current view controller even if it's a modal.

```
func topViewController() -> UIViewController? {
    guard var topViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController else { return nil }
    while topViewController.presentedViewController != nil {
        topViewController = topViewController.presentedViewController!
    }
    return topViewController
}
```

So you can now obtain the controller and present the alert on it:

```
topViewController()?.present(alertController2, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need:

```
import UIKit
```

But your larger problem is that the present() method you're trying to use is a method of UIViewController objects, and also it only works on View Controllers whose view is already a part of the view hierarchy.

So I think you need to refactor your code a bit, and decide which view controller should launch your alert.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class Utility: NSObject{

  func showAlert(_ VC : UIViewController, andMessage message: String , handler :@escaping(UIAlertAction) -> Void){

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: message , preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style:UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: handler))
    VC.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

   }
}
```

Try this, this will work.